# Automatic detection of Arduino COM port in Matlab

Tags: matlab, arduino, serial-port

I don't want to use something like `serial ('COM2')` to read data from Arduino by Matlab.

Is there any way in Matlab to identify COM port of an Arduino board automatically?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`arduino`](https://mathworks.com/help/supportpkg/arduinoio/ref/arduino.html) command (from the *MATLAB Support Package for Arduino Hardware*) without any arguments:

> recreates the last successful connection to the Arduino® hardware. If
>   that connection fails, it creates a connection to the first official
>   Arduino hardware connected to your host computer via USB.